# VBA to compare values in two columns, and copy the row of missing values to a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I'm new to this, so really don't know where to start.

here is my best description the macro i'd like to achieve:

Compare all values in column "B" of worksheet "E Dump" to values in column "G" in worksheet "F Dump".

Any value that appears in column "B", but not column "E" copy that entire row from worksheet "E Dump" into the next available row on worksheet "Mismatch".

Any help much apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some working code i have just written. This could also be done using search functions but regardless this should work. My only other comment is that if you post your own attempts you are allot more likely to get a response!

```
Sub compareAndCopy()

Dim lastRowE As Integer
Dim lastRowF As Integer
Dim lastRowM As Integer
Dim foundTrue As Boolean

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowE = Sheets("E Dump").Cells(Sheets("E Dump").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
lastRowF = Sheets("F Dump").Cells(Sheets("F Dump").Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row
lastRowM = Sheets("Mismatch").Cells(Sheets("Mismatch").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row



For i = 1 To lastRowE
foundTrue = False
For j = 1 To lastRowF

    If Sheets("E Dump").Cells(i, 2).value = Sheets("F Dump").Cells(j, 7).value Then
        foundTrue = True
        Exit For
    End If

Next j

If Not foundTrue Then
    'MsgBox ("didnt find string: " & Sheets("E Dump").Cells(i, 2).value)
    Sheets("E Dump").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets("Mismatch").Rows(lastRowM + 1)
    lastRowM = lastRowM + 1

End If


Next i

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what i was looking for! I had made a workaround using the search functions but this is much cleaner. In future i'll ensure i have an attempt at writing some code before posting.